# Get Facebook's api to generate thumbnails

Tags: api, facebook, curl, facebook-opengraph

When I paste a URL on Facebook to create a new post, facebook automatically reads the open graph data on that address and generates a thumbnail with a picture, title and description.

I am trying to do the same with the Facebook API. I've already have the app set up and already posted some things. But unlikely the site, with the API, the posts only displays the URL and not the extracted meta data.

Does anyone know how to achieve this?

Note: I don't own the domain of the URLs I am trying to post.

Comment: Which URL are you posting and how are you posting it?

Comment: @WizKid I am using curl to send a post request to graph.facebook.com/{page-id-goes-here}/feed
message=http://my-url.com ... Token.. app Id etc etc.
It works, it publishes to the page, but only the URL, I want a thumb with a picture, title and description.

Comment: Use the link attribute maybe as explained at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/pages/publishing/#publish-a-link

Answer (score -1):

It seems that we need to use the `link` attribute.

Funny thing is, yesterday I used link and facebook complained about me not owning the domain ( of the link ).

Moral of the story: Facebook's documentation is pure trash.

Thank you @WizKid for the help.

Comment: What "link" attribute? Can you be more specific please!